# tSQL: Get average amount of time from record creation to first contact

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, average

I have a CRM database with primary table columns `createon` (`date`) & `createat` (`time`). We'll call it table A

There is a secondary table that is used to log data concerning activity taken in an attempt to contact records created in A, let's call this table B.

I'm trying to write a tSQL query that will show the average time it takes between when a record is created in A & the first activity is logged in B.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    B.userid,
    avg(cast(datediff(MINUTE, A.createat, B.ontime) as float)) 
    AS 'AVG TIME FROM LEAD CREATION TO FIRST LOGGED ACTIVITY'
FROM 
    TableA A, TableB B
WHERE 
    A.KEY_value = B.KEY_value
    AND B.USERID in ('USER1','USER2','USER3','USER4','USER5')
    AND B.ONDATE > '09/01/2014' 
GROUP BY 
    B.USERID
HAVING 
    B.ontime = min(B.ontime)
```

The query will work if I remove the 'having' clause, but then I can't be sure I'm getting the time of the first logged activity in Table B (min(B.ontime))

I'm still a SQL novice so any help/guidance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s: Discouraged by whom?

Comment: By anyone who likes for queries to be understandable.

Comment: There are several reasons to use ANSI Joins: Portability, finer control over joining vs filtering, less ambiguity when using several outer joins, and the ability to use UNION joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do is do get minimum ontime for each user in a subquery and join with table A.

```
SELECT
    T.userid,
    ISNULL(avg(cast(datediff(MINUTE, cast(A.createat as datetime)+A.createdon, T.MinOnTime) as float)),0) 
    AS [AVG TIME FROM LEAD CREATION TO FIRST LOGGED ACTIVITY]
FROM 
TableA A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Key_value, userid, min(cast(B.ontime as datetime) + B.ondate) as MinOnTime FROM 
                TableB B
                WHERE B.USERID in ('USER1','USER2','USER3','USER4','USER5')
                      AND B.ONDATE > '09/01/2014' 
                GROUP BY KEY_Value, userid
              )  T
on  A.KEY_value = T.KEY_value
GROUP BY T.userid
```

Comment: This seemed to work after I added a GROUP BY clause to the end, but I have a user with a negative aggregate value. How do I account for the user who does not log an activity in B on the same date as the A.createon date?

Comment: if Op is getting negative avergaes doesnt that mean that the op keys arent lining up the times correctly?

how would the first logged activity be before created time?

Comment: @RADAR Can I add together a.createon+a.createat AS [CreateDateTime] (in minutes) & T.MinOnDate+T.MinOnTime AS [MinOnDateTime] (in minutes) and use the variables in ISNULL(avg(cast(datediff(MINUTE, CreateDateTime, MinOnDateTime) as float)),0)

Comment: @lookslikeanevo I think we need to take the createon date and activity ondate into account...(See above)

Comment: @jer_bear, is ontime integer or date time, does it store only time component or minutes

Comment: proper way of combining date + time 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server

Comment: @RADAR A.createon & B.ondate are datetime() A.createat and B.ontime are varchar()

Comment: @RADAR createat and ontime are stored as follows: [00:00] in military time so if it were 1:33 pm it would show in the db as [13:33]

Comment: @jet_bear, updated the answer, you can cast the varchar to date time and then sum up the date values.

Comment: @RADAR updated my query to match yours but now I'm getting negative values for all of my users???

Comment: @jer_bear, interchange the cast value , move it after + instead of before

Comment: @RADAR I tried moving the cast value for both createat and ontime.
No change :/
Still returning negative values.

Comment: @RADAR Had to play with it a little bit, but ended up using your method. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @jer_bear, i am glad the query helped you.

Comment: @RADAR I ran into an issue. If a record has an activity logged on it by more than one user the query is simply grabbing the min(ondate) for each user. I want it to pull the min(ondate) period. Not per user. Ex. Record1 created 11/01/14. User1 logs first activity 11/02/14. Record1 is assigned to User2. User2 logs first activity 11/05/14. The query is getting the difference between 11/01/14 & 11/02/14 for user1 and 11/01/14 & 11/05/14 for user2. I only want it to calculate for User1 and disregard user2's logged activity since it was not the first logged activity for the record.

Comment: @jet_bear, the query becomes,. SELECT
    b.userid,
    ISNULL(avg(cast(datediff(MINUTE, cast(A.createat as datetime)+A.createdon, T.MinOnTime) as float)),0) 
    AS [AVG TIME FROM LEAD CREATION TO FIRST LOGGED ACTIVITY]
FROM 
TableA A
join Table B
on A.key_value = B.key_value
group by b.userid
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT  min(cast(B.ontime as datetime) + B.ondate) as MinOnTime FROM 
                TableB B
                WHERE B.USERID in ('USER1','USER2','USER3','USER4','USER5')
                      AND B.ONDATE > '09/01/2014' 
              )  T

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
        t.userid
        ,case when A.createon = B.ondate then avg(cast(datediff(MINUTE, A.createat, B.ontime) as float))
            else avg(datediff(MINUTE, A.createon, B.ondate)+(cast(datediff(MINUTE, A.createat, B.ontime) as float)))
                end  as 'AVG TIME FROM LEAD CREATION TO FIRST LOGGED ACTIVITY'
    FROM 
    TableA a
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Key_value, userid, min(B.ontime) as MinOnTime 
                    FROM TableB b
                    WHERE b.USERID in ('USER1','USER2','USER3','USER4','USER5')
                          and b.ondate > '2014/09/01' 

                    GROUP BY KEY_Value, userid) t on a.KEY_value = t.KEY_value
GROUP BY 
t.userid
```

Comment: I have to take into account the createon date and ondate. The createat & ontime times are stored as varchar() values whereas the ondate and createon dates are stored as datetime(). 
I could have a record with a createat time as [13:00] (i.e. the record was created at 1:00pm) but have a ontime the next day of [12:00] (i.e. the first logged activity wasn't logged until 12:00pm the following day). In this scenario I would end up with a negative aggregate value. Have to take into account the datetime() fields.

Comment: @jer_bear ok got it...will revise shortly and just add a case statement

Comment: @lookslikeanevo As an FYI, you can delete an answer so it doesn't show up while you're revising it, then undelete it when you finish the revisions.

Comment: @jer_bear you have any sample data to we can test the output?

Comment: @lookslikeanevo No, unfortunately I don't. I'm not sure how I would get you some even if I had it. Would I just select * the top x number of rows from table A & B and send it to you?

Comment: @jer_bear post it here top 5 or 10 rows  with similar "keys"

Comment: @jer_bear i revised again, hopefully you can get some sample data so i can test

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    B.userid,
    avg(cast(datediff(MINUTE, A.createat, min(B.ontime)) as float)) 
    AS 'AVG TIME FROM LEAD CREATION TO FIRST LOGGED ACTIVITY'
FROM 
    TableA A, TableB B
WHERE 
    A.KEY_value = B.KEY_value
    AND B.USERID in ('USER1','USER2','USER3','USER4','USER5')
    AND B.ONDATE > '09/01/2014' 
GROUP BY 
    B.USERID
```